# How can we implement offline leaflet map functionality in Cordova and jQuery mobile

Tags: cordova, leaflet

I want to implement offline map function. I have polygon points of map. I just want to download selected area covered under polygon points.

I want this functionality should be work in background.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Kothic](https://github.com/kothic/kothic-js), It should be more than capable of handling offline osm files. I guess Kothic will also be a tad easier to implement (pure JS). Additionally, Kothic claims easy integration with Leaflet, so I imagine this should suit you quite well.

Comment: above module developed in npm. it need node.js and NPM. But I need functionality for jquery mobile